# open activity with if and open another with else

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication

I'm creating app with firebase auth, when the user logs in with email and password the user gets sent to mainaActivity which works perfectly, I want to send a user with email "admin@admin.com or admin1@admin.com or admin2@admin.com" to main2Activity.
Note; I have added 3 users in firebase with above said emails.

```
package xxxx.xxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    // set the view now
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.gass_icon_144);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    toolbar.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.title_2));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_password);
    // get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SelectActivity.class));
        }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            String admin1 = "admin@admin.com";
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else if (inputEmail.getText().toString().equals(admin1)) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am not sure where the problem is.
I have struggling for 2 days now

**Edit**

I found the solution to my problem.
I added the string here

```
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    String admin = "admin@admin.com";
    String admin1 = "admin1@admin.com";
    String admin2 = "admin2@admin.com";
```

and changed the else if statement

```
    } else if (email.equals(admin)){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from this :

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

It will always redirects you to `MainActivty` no matter what email you are using. 
You need to get the email using `auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();` and test your condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Firebase's Custom Claims, essentially it allows you define custom attributes on user accounts, such as roles. This would be a great place to set an 'admin' flag for your admin accounts.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

This would be a lot safer than checking in code, as anyone can view your source code and would know that there is an "admin@admin.com" account. Then they're going to focus on gaining access to that account.

You can easily set these values in Python, using the Firebase Admin SDK.

```
# Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
auth.set_custom_user_claims(uid, {'admin': True})
# The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
# next time a new one is issued.
```

And then within your Android app, you can check if the user is an Admin or not.

```
user.getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult result) {
    boolean isAdmin = result.getClaims().get("admin");
    if (isAdmin) {
      // Show admin UI.
      showAdminUI();
    } else {
      // Show regular user UI.
      showRegularUI();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate you are checking for a logged in instance already here
It will skip automatically to MainActivity regardless of current email. You could use the if else statement. You could create a method with to run both when checking for current user or on logging in.
Example would be

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
String currentuseremail = user.getEmail();

if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in do method
} else {
    // No user is signed in carry out yourlogic
}
//check current user email. **Declare emails appropriately** and user
String adminone = "admin@admin.com";  
String admintwo = "admin2@admin.com";
String adminthree = "admin3@admin.com"; 

private void admincheck(){
if(currentuseremail.equals(adminone)){
//go to mainactivity needed
}
else if(currentuseremail.equals(admintwo)){
//update with mainactivity2
}
//and so on
}
```

Call this method on if task is successfull in OnComplete. Did this and it worked. If it does not I'll be happy to help